# Как должен выглядеть этот же запрос в linq

Tags: c#, linq

StudentsOfFaculti - это студенты. 
contextDB.tableBalli - это баллы студентов по разным дисциплинам.Таблицы связаны по ID_Studenta. Я нахожу студентов у которых по всем дисциплинам больше 40 баллов. Если у студента хотя бы по одной дисциплине меньше 40 то пропускаю этого студента. Не знаю как написать linq запрос, чтобы был тот же результат.

```
int AbsolutnayaUspevaemost = 0;

foreach (var ksf in StudentsOfFaculti)
{
    foreach (var b in contextDB.tableBalli)
    {
        if (ksf.ID == b.ID_Studenta && b.Itog >= 41)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            AbsolutnayaUspevaemost--;
            break;
        }
    }
    AbsolutnayaUspevaemost++;
}
```

Comment: Ааааа! Квадратичные запросы!

Comment: @VladD, эм... поясни?

Comment: А что делает этот запрос? какая-то странная логика

Comment: StudentsOfFaculti - это студенты
contextDB.tableBalli - это баллы студентов по разным дисциплинам.
Я нахожу студентов у которых по всем дисциплинам больше 40 баллов. Если у студента хотя бы по одной дисциплине меньше 40 то пропускаю этого студента.

Comment: добавь пояснения в сам вопрос: [edit]

Comment: @Grundy: ну, вместо джойна делается подзапрос на каждого студента.

Comment: Может кто-нибудь написать сам запрос?

Answer (score 4):

Пока вот сообразил такое решение - выдает количество неуспевающих:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>
        {
            new Student { ID = 0 },
            new Student { ID = 1 },
            new Student { ID = 2 },
            new Student { ID = 3 },
            new Student { ID = 4 },
            new Student { ID = 5 },
            new Student { ID = 6 },
            new Student { ID = 7 },
            new Student { ID = 8 },
            new Student { ID = 9 }
        };
        List<Mark> marks = new List<Mark>
        {
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 0, Itog = 41 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 0, Itog = 48 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 0, Itog = 43 },

            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 1, Itog = 40 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 1, Itog = 41 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 1, Itog = 28 },

            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 2, Itog = 50 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 2, Itog = 55 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 2, Itog = 59 },

            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 3, Itog = 30 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 3, Itog = 29 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 3, Itog = 36 },

            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 4, Itog = 48 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 4, Itog = 46 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 4, Itog = 42 },

            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 5, Itog = 41 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 5, Itog = 40 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 5, Itog = 43 },

            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 6, Itog = 39 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 6, Itog = 42 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 6, Itog = 46 },

            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 7, Itog = 30 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 7, Itog = 30 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 7, Itog = 50 },

            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 8, Itog = 45 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 8, Itog = 46 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 8, Itog = 49 },

            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 9, Itog = 40 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 9, Itog = 38 },
            new Mark { ID_Studenta = 9, Itog = 48 }
        };

        int c = students.Join(marks, s => s.ID, m => m.ID_Studenta, (s, m) => new { id = s.ID, itog = m.Itog })
                        .Where(a => a.itog < 41)
                        .GroupBy(a => a.id)
                        .Count();
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}

class Student
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
}

class Mark
{
    public long ID_Studenta { get; set; }
    public int Itog { get; set; }
}
```

Более грамотное решение могли бы вам дать специалисты по SQL, возможно стоит добавить сюда такую метку

Comment: К сожалению пока работает неправильно. Возьмем к примеру студента с ID_Studenta=7 из примера Андрея. У этого студента есть 3 значения 30, 30 и 50 то есть 2 значения у него меньше сорока (оговорюсь сразу что условие я поменял на .Where(a => a.itog > 41) и его считать не надо. Но запрос его считает. Запрос должен считать студента если все значения будут больше 40. Если хотя бы одно значение меньше 40 то он его не должен считать.

Comment: @Vivus если решение вам не подходит, зачем ставить отметку "Принято"? Это сбивает с толку.

Comment: @Vivus судя по вашему комментарию, достаточно использовать следующий запрос: `marks.GroupBy(mark => mark.ID_Studenta).Where(group => group.All(value => value.Itog >= 41)).Count();`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lRSDjl

Comment: Ну вот если условие поменять - то, конечно, не будет правильно работать, но если ваша цель - просто определить количество успевающих - считаете как у меня, затем вычитаете из общего числа. Если же конечная цель получить именно коллекцию успевающих, то мой вариант вам не подойдёт.

Answer (score 2):

Возвращает количество студентов, все оценки которых превышают порог в 40 баллов.

```
class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Mark
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

...

var threshold = 40;
var count = students
    .Join(marks, x => x.Id, x => x.StudentId, (x, y) => new { StudentId = x.Id, StudentMark = y.Value })
    .GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)
    .Where(x => !x.Any(y => y.StudentMark <= threshold))
    .Count();
```

---

Если в таблице с оценками нет оценок каких-то "левых" студентов, отсутствующих в таблице студентов, то от `Join` можно избавится как от лишней операции:

```
var count = marks
    .GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)
    .Where(x => !x.Any(y => y.Value <= threshold))
    .Count();
```

---

Но, вообще, в логике вашего цикла что-то сильно не так. В тело условия `else` мы попадаем в двух случаях:

- оценка некоторого студента является неудовлетворительной;
- это вообще оценка какого-то другого студента, а не того, которого
  мы рассматриваем в настоящий момент.

Таким образом, цикл прерывается и результирующее значение уменьшается каждый раз, когда мы просто натыкаемся не на того студента. Чтобы такого не происходило, цикл можно переписать примерно следующим образом:

```
var result = 0;
foreach (var student in students)
{
    result += 1;
    //
    foreach (var mark in marks.Where(x => x.StudentId == student.Id))
    {
        if (mark.Value <= threshold)
        {
            result -= 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Тот же вариант, что и у @Андрей, но в другом стиле:

```
int c = (from mark in marks
         from student in students
         where mark.ID_Studenta == student.ID && mark.Itog < 41
         group student by student.ID).Count();
```

Вариант с Join

```
int c = (from mark in marks
         join student in students on mark.ID_Studenta equals student.ID
         where mark.Itog < 41
         group student by student.ID).Count();
```

Comment: К сожалению тут тоже самое что я вверху описал.